# How to edit blog post HTML when using CloudScribe

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core, cloudscribe

I've just integrated a blog engine into my website using CloudScribe. I've been able to add my own theme and I've found it really impressive, can't wait to work with it more

What I want to do next is cutomise the HTML that is output at @RenderBody in _Layout - ie, I want to control POSTS view and POST view, has anybody done this yet, or knows where I can look to figure it out - I'll be searching in the meantime.

Thanks go to Joe Audette for a great piece of work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cloudscribe by default the views are used directly from a nuget package as embedded resources but any view can be customized by copying it to the local file system, the local view will be automatically used in preference to the embedded one allowing you to easily customize it. You can find the views for cloudscribe simple content [here on github](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.SimpleContent/tree/master/src/cloudscribe.SimpleContent.Web.Views.Bootstrap3/Views)

Note that I recommend only copy the views locally that you need to customize and let the rest of them be used from embedded resources because it is possible the built in views would be changed in future releases. So when upgrading to newer versions it may be a good idea to compare your custom views to the current embedded version.

For more information on customizing views in cloudscribe also see the documentation on [themes and web design](https://www.cloudscribe.com/docs/themes-and-web-design)

Comment: Hi Joe, appreciate your reply, thanks. It's probably something quite simple, I'm a VB developer and only just getting into MVC Core with C Sharp now (keen to become an ex VB Developer!), so forgive me that I haven't quite understood

Comment: oops - pressed enter too soon - When I open the CloudScribe master source code,I can see in the project 'Bootstrap3' lots of views which are clearly named, so I understand in principal. I just hoped to find a view called 'Post' and 'Posts', they probably are in a different project to bootstrap3? Without seeing them as file system objects, I wouldn't know what to name my local copies of them.

Comment: Sorted it now, I had the source code for CloudScribe Master, and the starter kits, but didn't have the source code for SimpleContent.